# Spring Boot Application deployment on remote server

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a Java Spring Boot Application, and I build it with Maven. With 
`spring-boot-maven-plugin`,

I can create fat, executable jar file.
Then I copy it to the remote server and run. But sometimes,

I change only one line or event one word in my code and I had to do whole build/copy step again. I'm sure that I'm doing it wrong, but I couldn't find another way that more efficient (Like capistrano in Rails).

At this point, I'm planning to clone source code to server, push from local, pull from remote, build and run approach. What is the correct (or elegant) way of doing this deployment?

Comment: You can go for `Jenkins`

Comment: Thanks @KrishnanunniPV, I will give a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For automatic build and deployment process (continuous integration), you can use **Jenkins**. Refer this documentation for more details: https://jenkins.io/doc/

Comment: Doesn't do anything to answer question of how to do it, eg with Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends where are you trying to do it.

The best and the most agile way to do it for a controlled environment is surely a CI-CD (Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment) pipelines, which complies-builds-tests-deploys your code against every commit made to the source code **BUT** it may be too slow to use CI-CD for a development environment where you had like to have a shorter feedback cycle and faster feedback to see how the code is progressing.

However, **if you are talking about development environment**, I will hit another chord and ask you why to deploy to the external server ***AT ALL*** while developing. When you use Spring Boot, which helps you develop a self-contained application, you get the Tomcat Server embedded with it for free. That gives you the choice to run the code anywhere you develop and test to move forward.

A simple maven goal - `mvn spring-boot:run` can make the code run anywhere you had like.

There is another magical library available in Spring-Boot, known as [Devtools](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html), which is meant to support agile developers. The library once in the app classpath, performs hot-swapping of byte-code to auto reload of code into the running application (*running locally with embedded Tomcat*) as soon there is a saved change. This is one of the coolest gadget that a developer can have.

Use of [Spring-Loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded) (or [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) for non spring-boot apps) libraries can also help a developer do hot-swapping of byte code to load changes in running application as soon saved.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I have database operations in application and I don't want to run application on local due to network delay to database. Also application has RestAPI, so when I run application in local, I need to change all clients target address to my local address, which is not achievable always. However, you're totally right about it is not common to deploy remote server on development phase. I'm confused and trying to find optimum (less effort) way of development in my case.

Comment: Even I have apps that contain Database ops but then for development I prefer to use the embedded one for testing and local installations of DB (MySql in my case) for local run instead, again for the benefit of shorter feedback cycles. SpringBoot and Maven Scopes make it easy to use embedded for tests and a real one when the app is run locally. Switching of url should be pretty easy again if you use the profiles -https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html of Spring, by which it's just a matter of setting right profile as needed.

Comment: My concern is, since I serve RESTApi in my application, when I run it locally, I need to change endpoint URI of all clients. This is something I can't do everytime. Based on your suggestions, I will try to set up more reasonable development environment.

Comment: I would still argue and suggest you use profiling to avoid manual replacement of endpoint URIs when you run locally. Something like this: `endPoint.uri01=mylocalURI` in **application-local.properties** files as configuration and then inject the value at runtime using `@Value("${endPoint.uri01}")
    private String URI01;`
in the application code. This profiling helps you use different values for different places/env you run code, without any manual changes everytime.